# Slow SQL Query speed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query (below) that takes forever to run when a customer has a lot of categories. I need to speed it up somehow and I can't figure out how. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
 SELECT pictures1.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cats_master.categoryName SEPARATOR ';') AS categoryNames
            FROM pictures1
                LEFT JOIN cats_contacts ON pictures1.id =cats_contacts.contact_id
                LEFT JOIN cats_master ON cats_contacts.category_id = cats_master.id
            WHERE pictures1.customer_id = (customer id goes here)
            GROUP BY pictures1.id
            ORDER BY pictures1.l_name ASC
```

The result of this query is a file that the customer can download - the issue seems to be the category piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having following indexes will greatly speedup the query:

```
id, l_name, customer_id: pictures table
contact_id: cats_contacts table
id, category_id: cats_master table
```

Comment: Thanks Raihan - for the pictures table - are you suggesting one index with those 3 fields or 3 indexes? This part is a bit confusing for me.  

right now i have the following indexes:  
    
    cats_contacts: name:category_id fields:category_id,contact_id <-- setup as one index it looks like, index type Unique  

    cats_master: one on customer_id and one on categoryName (just created this categoryName index) - both index type Normal

Comment: (i have tried about 100 times now to fix up the look of this comment, even reading the help doc and it is still ugly. sorry about that)

Comment: All indexes should be on single columns, no composite index required based on your query. So 3 indexes on `pictures` table, 1 on `cats_contacts`, 2 on `cats_master`. If any of the columns is a primary key, make it a unique index.

Comment: BTW - you were right Raihan - I added an index to the contact_id in cats_contacts and instantly the query and the resulting file is so quick - before it crashed the server when a customer had a lot of records and categories. You rock!

Answer (score 3):

Check the explain plan and add indexes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try an index on all the ids, + l_name for the final sort. After that it's nitty gritty time. For instance are all your 'join' ids the same type and size.

PS What does query plan say.

and outside chance rebuild the indexes, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you Tony - not sure if it matters but the explain does say "using temporary, using filesort"

Comment: Can you add it to the question? We might be able to give you more clues, then. SQL performamnce tuning is an art as much as it is a science